# Using CASE statements on Google Data Studio for two layers of filtering?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to filter my campaign data on GDS in two steps:

Step 1: Filter out just my Search campaigns
Step 2: Within Search, split campaigns into 'Brand', 'Dynamic Search' and 'Generic'

I've been able to do Step 2 using CASE, as follows:

```
CASE
 WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, '.*(Brand).*') THEN 'Brand'
 WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, '.*(Generic).*') THEN 'Generic'
 WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, '.*(DSA).*') THEN 'Dynamic Search'
END
```

While this serves to separate out my Brand, Generic and Dynamic Search campaigns, I still have another row called 'null' that shows metrics from a bunch of other campaigns - Shopping, Display, Video, etc. Attaching a screengrab as well.

[image: GDS Issue]

So my question is, how do I apply two layers of filters, so GDS first narrows the campaigns down to Search only, so I can then get campaign metrics split by Brand, Generic and DSA?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [As of REVISION 1] **Needs details**: Could you provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (TO-DO) (and sample data set(s) / Google Sheet (TO-DO)) of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~9 rows) (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 2) Expected output (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO)) 3) An attempt at solving the issue (in both Report (TO-DO) & Question (TO-DO))? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case

Answer (score -1):

Okay so I've found a way around this by using CASE to bucket campaigns into Brand, Generic and DSA, and then adding a regular filter from the 'Data' section. I'd still like to know if applying two filters is doable using CASE.

Comment: [As of REVISION 1] **This answer is unclear** as the question and now the answer lacks tables of data**: Could you provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report  of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~9 rows) 2) Actual output. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and understand